# Cannot get the headers after I set the mapping template in API GATEWAY

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I would like to call an api with a header and body for admin user delete a user data like this:

```
apiClient.post('***endpoint***',
    { tableName: '***',
      id: id },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: accessToken
      }
    })
```

and I want to show the detail in lambda first before I write any function to access my db:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: '***' })
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()

exports.handler = async function (event , ctx , callback) {
    return event
};
```

and in APIGATEWAY, I set the following

```
{ 
    "Authorization" : "$input.params('Authorization'),
    "body" : $input.json('$') 
}
```

with content-type is`application/json` in  Integration Request 
Then when I test the api in  Method Test .
In Header , I type `"testaccesstoken"`,
In body , I type `{ "id":"1", "tableName":"test"}`,
But the result is`{
  "Authorization": "",
  "body": {
    "id": "1",
    "tableName": "test"
  }
}`
Can anyone explain to me why I still cannot get the header?
Also when I test in poseman,I try like this:[image],
[image] and I get an error[image]

I hv already deployed the API but why I cannot test in postman??

Answer (score 1):

In your Postman, set your header is `Authorization` instead of `"Authorization"`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you mentioned the mapping template and passthrough behavior but nothing about mapping it in your Method Request or the header field in Integration Request in API Gateway. There is a recent [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106225/aws-api-gateway-method-request-path-parameter-not-working/58108659#58108659) I think may give you some things to verify are set correctly, as I suspect that may be the issue.

It also covers using a proxy integration instead, let me know if there is a more specific issue in the comments and I'll adjust my answer if needed!