# AWS - API Gateway - HTTPS Request returning 404 Not Found

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I am working on creating a new request in AWS API Gateway. I am having issues with a 404 not found on the URL request.

The request (had to create fake one for the question):

```
GET https://hello.stackoverflow.com/services/misc/myroute/v1/swagger.json
```

I created a route in API Gateway `ANY /services/misc/myroute/{proxy+}`

I attached the route to a Load Balancer Listener integration

I set up the listener rule in the Load Balancer:

```
IF Path is /services/misc* Then Forward to Target
IF Requests otherwise not routed Then Forward to Default
```

Created logs for this system in the AWS API Gateway: Monitor -> Logging -> Set Log Destination

Set variables for the log format using the $context variables, [Context Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-logging-variables.html)

Ex Log:

```
{ "requestId":"QWRHQKWFHWAFZ=", 
  "routeKey":"ANY /services/misc/myroute/{proxy+}", 
  "path":"/services/misc/myroute/v1/swagger.json", 
  "domain":"hello.stackoverflow.com", 
  "domain_prefix":"hello", 
  "httpMethod":"GET", "status":"404","protocol":"HTTP/1.1", "endpoint":-" }
```

One final check I have done to make sure its completing its "route" was see the requests in the monitoring and seeing the 4xx come from this ALB listener.

I can send the request via localhost and get a response with the json body

GET https://localhost:8080/v1/swagger.json --> Status 200 OK with body filled

In my quest to solve the issue, it has lead me to many older (2019) stack overflow questions that seem to be outdated with the AWS Console, same with the AWS documentation. See links below...

[AWS API Gateway Method request path parameter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106225/aws-api-gateway-method-request-path-parameter-not-working/58108659#58108659)

[AWS API Gateway 404 page not found error when invoking endpoint url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089140/aws-api-gateway-404-page-not-found-error-when-invoking-endpoint-url/58103291#58103291)

[AWS API Gateway Method request path parameter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106225/aws-api-gateway-method-request-path-parameter-not-working/58108659#58108659)

With this being my first project in the AWS cloud space, I am not sure where else to turn. My guess would be the authentication headers from the API Gateway are being lost, but not sure where I can see this loss happening.

From my understanding of how the AWS Request Flow goes, I created this diagram:

[image]

Comment: could it be the route forward to  `localhost:8080/services/misc/myroute/v1/swagger.json` not `localhost:8080/v1/swagger.json` ?

Comment: did you try using postman to intercept the request and check if the authentication headers are there when it's sent?

Comment: did you fwd to port 8080?

Comment: @uingtea I believe looking @ the logs that the route is sent to where it should be, Ive compared the output of existing routes and they have the same format minus the `v1/swagger.json`. I.E. `localhost:8080/services/misc/myroute/getinfo` works fine

Comment: @Baby_Boy yep I have been working side by side with Postman, nothing seems out of place which is odd

Comment: @flaxon yes I did

Comment: @Baby_Boy I think whats happening, is that the auth headers get lost inside of the VPC, and never resurface. Postman shows that they exist, but Im wondering if they get left before the request is consumed later in the VPC

Comment: @Travis if its not getting lost on your end you might want to try contacting AWS support, also are you using a custom Authorizer?